# Switch Statement in SRSS

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, switch-statement

i want to have conditional formatting of the background color of a textbox. i want something like this. IF i ican use the If - else statement its still ok.

```
  =Switch

     (
       (First(Fields!Risk_Level.Value, "BBS_ID") = "high","Red"),
       (First(Fields!Risk_Level.Value, "BBS_ID") = "Medium","Orange"),
       (First(Fields!Risk_Level.Value, "BBS_ID") = "Low","Green")
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
=Switch(
        Fields!Risk_Level.Value = "high","Red",
        Fields!Risk_Level.Value = "Medium","Orange",
        Fields!Risk_Level.Value = "Low","Green"
       )
```

Comment: Thanx Mark. IT works. However the expression is evaluating the first row and applying the same color to all rows. i want it to evaluate row by row. currently had made the switch statement the expression for column background color.

Comment: @user2194058: Sorry, I thought that was what you wanted based on the question - I have amended my answer.